# How to save images into Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, image

I'd like to know if there's a way to save Images (of the type .gif) to the sqllite-database. If yes how should my `DatabaseAdapter` look like.

Also is there a performance issue?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should use `BLOB` in your database:

Check [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20200718180158/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/how-to-insert-image-data-to-sqlite.html)...

But I think you should download and store image in HashMap, which will make it simpler.

Code:

**Stroring**

```
var imageMap = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();

var imageUrl = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLjuP.jpg";

var imagedata = GetImage(imageUrl);      

imageMap.put("img",imagedata);
```

**Retrieving**

```
var imageData = imageMap.get("img");

var imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);

var image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
```

**GetImage**

```
private byte[] GetImage(String url)
{
    try
    {
        var imageUrl = new URL(url);
        var urlConnection = imageUrl.openConnection();

        var inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        var bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

        var byteArrayBuffer = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);
        
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1)
        {
            byteArrayBuffer.append((byte)current);
        }

        return byteArrayBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }       
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: well that is kind of data type, no not much effect on DB. http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_load_blob.html

Comment: Well maybe it does not have any effect on DB, but how about overall performance? I doubt that DB is faster then normal file loading

Comment: @BojanKogoj DB will be faster if one's going to use bunch of images (hundreds or thousands) - in this case DB is preferable comparing to FS

Comment: Why not use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(hh.get("img"), 0, 0)` to decode the image instead of creating an additional stream?

Answer (score 6):

There's nothing special in storing image to SQLite. Just create table with BLOB record type and do smth like:

```
protected long saveBitmap(SQLiteDatabase database, Bitmap bmp)
{
    int size = bmp.getRowBytes() * bmp.getHeight(); 
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(size); bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(b); 
    byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
    b.get(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(CHUNK, bytes);
    this.id= database.insert(TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

Probably you migth want to save image chunk by chunk, since there's limits/recommended BLOB size (don't really recall how much)

Comment: can I only insert bitmap pictures or does it also work with gif's png's and so on?

Comment: It doesn't matter which format of image u're going to insert. Any image can be represented as Android Bitmap - which is not actually Windows BMP (name is confusing), but just internal representation of PNG/GIF/JPEG/and so on in Android