# How to set image to checkbox from sqlite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Is there a way to set image to checkbox from prepopulated sqlite database? Or somehow connect checkbox to an image from database. The problem is that I have to shuffle images from database, and the user needs to select two of 5 images using checkbox (or some other way, but I've come up with nothing but checkbox idea). If I did not have to shuffle images I would simply put a checkbox below every image and I would know what image is selected when I user check a box, but this way I would not know where my images are.

Comment: So, inflate your Layout, I don't understand where it becomes difficult and what is your problem!

Answer (score 0):

See this: http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/android-custom-image-gallery-with-checkbox-in-grid-to-select-multiple

and this [How to save images into Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512019/how-to-save-images-into-database) to get a image bitmap from stream.

you can use a adapter to set bitmat into each image in gallery.

I hope this could help you.