# How to insert an image in a database and retrieve it in a listview

Tags: java, android, json, listview, base64

I am developing an app in Android. After looking so much I am still trying to find the working code insert an image in a database and retrieve it in a listview. I would like to store it in the database encoding and decoding in base64 but if you can suggest me a working alternative I am all for it.

Comment: This question has been answered before. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512019/how-to-save-images-into-database

Comment: You can do that with a sqlite db, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331310/how-to-store-image-as-blob-in-sqlite-how-to-retrieve-it

Comment: Thanks VonL and sjkm but I need to store the images on a server. It's my bad I didn't mentioned