# Store an image in MySQL database and display it in ImageView in Android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, imageview

I am new to Android development. I am just trying to store an image in MySQL database and want to display that image in an ImageView.

What should I do?

I think I have to store the URL of image in MySQL database but I don't know how to do it either.

I am using PHP too.

Comment: Hmm, so how much have you tried so far?

Comment: You are new to development it seems

Answer (score 1):

One method is to store the base64 version of image using a php script with
base64_encode() wich returns the base64 encryption of the image but i don't recommend it because this is increasing the size of the image.
You should upload the image to a server and only store in the database the path to the image and then load it inside the Android application.
Here is a nice Java tutorial that explains how to upload an image through HTTP http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=62798 it should work for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid if you can, storing images in database (as it would increase the size)..
If you cannot avoid, try using `BLOB` in database.. as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512019/how-to-save-images-into-database).

NOTE: Also do some research before asking questions.