# Android: How to store multiple images from recyclerview and retrieve them into imageids from the database

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-database

I have uploaded multiple images from gallery onto a recyclerview.
Now i want to store those images into the database and retrieve them in another activity where i need to place individual images into different image views having different image id's.
How should i go about doing?
Any help?

Comment: just save images path in `SharedPreferences` and get it in another activity

Answer (score 0):

databases support BLOB type data. Convert the image to blob type and save it.

[How to save images into Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512019/how-to-save-images-into-database)